# How could I get Laravel 5.2 Pagination for a collection being sent to a view?

Tags: php, pagination, eloquent, laravel-5, polymorphic-associations

I am using Laravel 5.2 and using a polymorphic relations table for a feeds page. A feed has pictures, articles, and links that have their own respective models. The controller method that I am using for the feed looks like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $allActivity = Activity::get();

    $activity = collect();

    foreach($allActivity as $act)
    {

        $modelString = $act->actable_type;
        $class = new $modelString();
        $model = $class->find($act->actable_id);

        $activity->push($model);
    }

    return view('feed', compact('activity'));
}
```

and here is the feed.blade.php view

```
  @foreach($activity as $class)
      // Gives me the model name so the correct partial view could be referenced
      <?php
            $split = explode("\\", get_class($class));
            $model = lcfirst($split[1]);
        ?>

      @include("partials.{$model}", [$model => $class])
    @endforeach
```

Because of this setup, I can't get pagination using the method outlined in the Laravel documentation. How could I correctly implement pagination using this setup? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access your relation using the `actable()` relation you should have on your `Activity` model.  It will also help you avoid using `find()` in the loop like you are which will give you an N+1 issue.

In your activity model you should have an `actable` method:

```
class Activity 
{
    public function actable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Then in your view you can lazy load all polymorphic actable relations and pass to the view.  You can even keep your view clean and resolve the model name in the `map()` function:

```
public function index()
{
    $activity = Activity::with('actable')->get()->map(function($activity) {
        $activity->actable->className = lcfirst(class_basename($activity->actable));
        return $activity->actable;
    });

    return view('feed', compact('activity'));
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@foreach($activity as $model)   
    @include("partials.{$model->className}", [$model->className => $class])
@endforeach
```

To run this with pagination it would be:

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $activities = Activity::with('actable')->paginate(25);

    return view('feed', compact('activities'));
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($activities as $activity)  
    @include('partials.'.lcfirst(class_basename($activity->actable)), [lcfirst(class_basename($activity->actable)) => $activity])
@endforeach
```

Comment: The pagination works like a charm, however when I tried to eliminate the n+1 using



 `public function index()
    {
        $activity = Activity::with('actable')->get()->map(function($activity) {
        $activity->actable->className = lcfirst(class_basename($activity- >actable));
        return $activity->actable;
    });

    return view('feed', compact('activity'));
}`

I receive the following error:


Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Activity::$actable has no effect

Comment: One of the models in the map function doesn't have an `actable` relation.  You could either filter the results before the map function or check if `actable` is an object before creating the `className` property then add an `@if` constraint in your blade loop.